# Rails 4 form remote to update div

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

I am upgrading my rails 2.3.8 app to rails 4 and I have a form_remote_tag that is not running on rails 4.

My orignal code:

view .erb

```
<% form_remote_tag :url => { :controller => :x, :action => :y  } do %>
  ...
<% end %>

<div id="changediv"> 
  <%= render :partial => 'y' %>
</div>
```

controller x.rb

```
def y
  ...
  render :update do |page|
    page.replace_html 'changediv', :partial => "partialview"
  end
end
```

_partialview.erb

```
some html code …..
```

And this is how I am trying to upgrade to rails 4, but is not running, What am i doing wrong?

view .erb

```
<%= form_tag(url_for(:action => 'y'), :remote => true) do %>

<% end %>

<div id="changediv">
  <%= render :partial => 'y' %>
</div>
```

controller x.rb

```
def y
  ...
  render :partial => 'partialview'
end
```

_partialview.erb

```
some html code …
```

Comment: You could first upgrade to 3.2 and then to rails 4. That would be easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with the `format.js` in controller `x.rb`

```
def y
  respond_to do |format|
   format.js 
  end
end
```

Also need to create `js.erb` for `y`

**y.js.erb**

```
$('#your_div').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'your_partial')%>");
```